# Can one still sort By Album By Year in any of the views in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes

In previous versions of iTunes, it was possible to sort songs by Artist, and then by Album By Year, so that albums would be shown in the order they were released, rather than alphabetical order.

I can't find a way to replicate this behaviour in any of the various views in iTunes 11: In the Songs view, I can only sort by a single column, and in the other views where songs are grouped by albums, the albums are always displayed in alphabetical order.

Is there an option I'm missing, or is sorting by Album By Year no longer an option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in the albums view go to the view menu and select viewing options (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>) and choose sort by year.

Here is a screenshot (in german but I hope you get the important points).

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In artist view press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (windows).

Then select "sort albums by year" in the popup.